# invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, types

```
struct Apartment {
    int floor;      // aparment's floor
};

void main() {
    Apartment apartments[10];// array containing all the apartments

    create_apartments(apartments);
};

void create_apartments(struct Apartment *apartments) {
   int i,pos;

   pos=0;
   for(i=0;i<10;i++){
       *(apartments+pos)->floor = i;  //error apears here!
        pos++;            
    }
}
```

invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’) appears at commented line. can someone tell me what's wrong? thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `->` operator already dereferences the pointer. Applying `*` again tries to dereference `(apartments+pos)->floor` which is of type `int`. Remove the `*`.

EDIT: It's even more common to just write this:

```
    apartments[pos].floor = i;
```

Comment: Because precedence of `->` operator is higher then `*` so expression pareses as `*((apartments+pos)->floor)` And `*` is applied on an `int` value hence compiler emits error message: `"invalid type argument of unary ‘*’ (have ‘int’)"`. Anyways using `*` with `->` is senseless! Even if one wants to uses `*` and `.`(dot) then he has to write `(*(apartments + pos)).floor` because precedence of `*` is lower then `.` operator. this also looks unnecessary complicate. using `[]` operator and we can write `apartments[pos].floor = i;`. Here we don't need any `()`  because `[]` precedence is higher ;)

Comment: `apartments[pos].floor = i;` parses as `(apartments[pos]).floor = i;`  because `apartments[pos]` is nothing but `*(apartments + pos )` so `(apartments[pos]).floor = i;` is same as `(*(apartments + pos)).floor = i;`